# Removing ActiveAdmin resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm on Rails 3.1.1, Ruby 1.9.2 and the latest gem (pulled from github).

It's easy enough to add a resource to the excellent ActiveAdmin gem for Ruby. I can see you can also remove a resource by deleting the relevant .rb file from app/admin.

I can't find anything in the documentation about it, but does anyone know is there another way the remove resources... or is deleting the ActiveAdmin resource file the correct way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, deleting the respective resource file under `app/admin` is the correct approach :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use

```
rails destroy active_admin:resource [ModelName]
```

to remove resource from ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Thomas Watson's answer, you also need to clean up references to the resource in your routes.rb file.